# How to use function with parameter as a props in react

Tags: reactjs

If we use function with parameters and want to use this function as a props for other component and when I try to `console.log(this.props)` in other component I get undefined.

```
         anotherfunctionCall = (ss) =>  {
               console.log(ss) 
          }

     <DrawerRight
        anotherfunctionCall = {this.anotherfunctionCall('some')}

      />
```

when i console(this.props) in other component i get undefined. please help to fix this. if i use anotherfunctionCall = (ss) => () => {
                   console.log(ss) 
              }
it's working

Answer (score 0):

Passing props the way you do now will not pass the function but instead will call it at the very moment the parent component is rendered.

Instead, change your code to this:

```
 <DrawerRight
    anotherfunctionCall={() => this.anotherfunctionCall('some')}
  />
```

Then from the DrawerRight component, you will use it as:

```
props.anotherfunctionCall();
```

Or if you want to call this function from DrawerRight component with custom prop, change code to:

```
 <DrawerRight
    anotherfunctionCall={this.anotherfunctionCall}
  />
```

And then in the DrawerRight use it like:

```
props.anotherfunctionCall('some other text');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the answer that you are looking for but, you pass a function as props to a component without any arguments. You just pass the function reference and call it from the child component with or without props. (however you defined it)

```
anotherfunctionCall = (ss) =>  {
               console.log(ss) 
          }

     <DrawerRight
        anotherfunctionCall = {this.anotherfunctionCall}

      />

//DrawerRight.js

...

componentDidMount(){
  this.props.anotherfunctionCall("test");
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few good ways to do this without incurring performance penalties,

**Case 1**: When you know the parameter value in the child component

```
    anotherfunctionCall = (ss) =>  {
        console.log(ss) 
    }

     <DrawerRight
        anotherfunctionCall = {this.anotherfunctionCall}
      />

// DrawerRight

this.props.anotherFunctionCall('some')
```

**Case 2**: When you do not know the parameter value in the child component, use a bound function to prevent unnecessary re-renders,

```
    constructor() {
       this.anotherFunctionCallSome = this.anotherFunctionCall.bind(null, 'some')
    }

    anotherfunctionCall = (ss) =>  {
        console.log(ss) 
    }

     <DrawerRight
        anotherfunctionCall = {this.anotherfunctionCallSome}
      />

// DrawerRight

this.props.anotherFunctionCall();
```

**Case 3**: When the parameter value is not fixed, and changes based on state, use an inline lambda/arrow function

```
     <DrawerRight
        anotherfunctionCall = {() => this.anotherfunctionCall(this.state.someValue)}
      />
```